# MatLab prompt error

Tags: matlab, prompt

Why doesn't my program run?

```
eyeGlassesColour=input ('Please, input your eye glasses colour:\n');
if eyeGlassesColour == 'red'
fprintf('They are pretty.\n');
else
fprintf('Buy another pair.\n');
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify that the user entry to the [input command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) is expected to be a string. So the first line of your code should be:

```
eyeGlassesColour=input ('Please, input your eye glasses colour:\n', 's');
```

with the 's' flag as the second argument.

Also, using the '==' operator requires that the two strings to be compared are exactly the same length, otherwise it produces a run-time error. Thus if the user enters something like 'blue' or 'green' it will produce an error instead of returning false and executing the else block. Therefore, it is better to use '[strcmp()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html)' to compare strings, as in the following:

```
if strcmp(eyeGlassesColour, 'red') == true
```

note that 'strcmp()' is case-sensitive, so if you want strings such as 'Red' or 'RED' to also return true, use the case-insensitive 'strcmpi()' instead.